# JQuery background-color chrome

Tags: jquery, css, hover, background-color, mouseenter

I got a problem with a sample which should change background color on hover event in JQuery. 
( line with `.css("background-color","rgba(78, 175, 212, 0.75)");`)

All others changes are working, even opacity, but not background-color which always changing for "`rgb(0, 0, 0)`".
This mistake appears only on Chrome, not on IE or Mozilla (all last versions).

I specify that class .over doesn't have properties background-color or opacity before the treatment.

Here is the sample :

```
jQuery(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        jQuery(".over, .overVideo",this).clearQueue()
                .css("display", "block")
                .css("height", "200px")
                .animate({height:'350px'},{duration:200})
                .css("opacity", "0.5")
                .css("background-color","rgba(78, 175, 212, 0.75)");

        jQuery(".blur, .blurVideo",this).clearQueue()
                .css("height", "200px")
                .animate({height: '350px'},{duration:200});
    },
```

...

I tried to move background-color line, I tried to set another type of color, like "blue", like "#fff", or like "rgb(12,12,12)", but always the same problem.

Can you help me ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/azmbftjq/1/?

Answer (score 0):

So i went on jsfiddle and made something which does what you ask.

HTML:

```
<div class="hoverme" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:black;">
```

jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hoverme').hover(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color","rgba(78,175,212,0.75)");
  })
});
```

It does the basic background color stuff, you just need to add the rest, it should solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use callback for animate method:

```
jQuery(".over, .overVideo",this).clearQueue()
     .css("display", "block")
     .css("height", "200px")
     .animate({height:'350px'},{duration:200},function(){
         $(this).css("opacity", "0.5")
         $(this).css("background-color","rgba(78, 175, 212, 0.75)");
})
```

I would also suggest you to css method to use like the following instead of single declaration:

```
.css({display: 'block',height: '200px'});
```

for short hand.